# Unable to check the checkbox in GEB

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, geb

I am trying to check my check box in Geb.

I have tried following codes, but no luck

```
$('input', type:'checkbox', id: 'chkTermsConditions', tabindex: '-1').value('true')
$(".CheckBoxUI").value('true')
```

Following is the HTML

[image]

After mouse go over the check box additional text updated (marked in the screen shot)

[image]

Comment: I am using Geb, Selenium Cucumber with Groovy

Comment: Does $('input', id: 'chkTermsConditions').click() work?

Comment: @BDKosher I am getting same error `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException `

Comment: and that particular checkbox is visible for you when Geb opens the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to check the check box with `$(".CheckBoxStyle").click()`

Only issue is still `Submit` button doesn't get enable. Following is the html code for before and after checking the check box in real situation.

I tried the to click on the submit button with following code. It doesn't give any error. But still doesn't move to next page as expected.May be because of `Submit` button disable issue.

```
$("#submitBtnMsg").click()
```

**Edited :**

It was turned out above was application related issue. We have to click on the address after selecting via address validation service. Then only `Submit` button get enable.

```
$(".RedColor").click()
```

Comment: As I explained in my answer it may best to call the javascript widget for your checkbox. It may trigger other ajax enabled events when the checkbox is clicked. Since you may be manually clicking the wrong element. If it is the proper element to click. Then you may have a found a bug on your page.

Comment: Maybe try the parent element: $('a[id=termLink]').parent().click()

Comment: @twinj Thax for your response. Just to let you know, I am getting  `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (570, 516). Other element would receive the click: <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">...</a> ` error with `$('a[id=termLink]').parent().click() `. Checking further

Comment: If I were to click on `href="javascript:void(0) ` in following How would I do that?  `<a data-tryagain-text="Try again" class="ButtonType ButtonType06 ap_form_submit_button" href="javascript:void(0);" id="register"> <span id="submitBtnMsg">Submit</span> </a> `

Comment: Tried this `$("#register").executeScript() ` No errors, Still the `Submit ` button doesn't get enabled though. Interesting part was when I assert the tittle of next page that I supposed to get after clicking `Submit ` button is working fine. But that page movement cannot visible in the browser when run the script.

Comment: @twinj Thanks for your time and advice. The second issue was application related one. I have updated in the answer. All working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to check the box which has the attribute with value='true'

From the Geb manual:

> The value of input, select and textarea elements can be retrieved and set with the value method. Calling value() with no arguments will return the String value of the first element in the Navigator. Calling value(value) will set the current value of all elements in the Navigator. The argument can be of any type and will be coerced to a String if necessary. **The exceptions are that when setting a checkbox value the method expects a boolean (or, an existing checkbox value)** and when setting a multiple select the method expects an array or Collection of values.

Try this:

$("#chkTermsConditions").value(true)

If you are using non standard HTML generated by some other platform. You may have to resort to clicking the element or using javascript.

The element that produces the desired click result could be one of the surrounding elements. If the widget is javascript controlled you may have to call a function that is embedded into the page for that widget. If its a javascript widget I cannot help you unless you can point me to a page which uses the same platform.

Try:

$('a[class=CheckRadioFocus]').click()

$('a[id=termLink]').click()

or any of the other surrounding elements.

Comment: I get `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException ` error with your code. I noticed another thing which is `html code ` get changed when mouse pointed to the check box. I attached that to the question

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that. Because I am working on testing stream. Just curious in case of this type of situations where elements will appear ONLY with mouse interaction (move over), how would we find the element within our script.

Comment: If you select $(..) using name or id you will still get the element event with class change. You can select by class using normal css selector e.g: $('element[id=someId].someclass') or just $('.SomeClass'). I would select the element and test if it contains the class. $('element[id=someId]').@class.contains("someClass") However, if you are using some product to generate html testing to this granularity is redundant. Test from a user perspective.

Comment: Also it would be best if you knew what was used to create your pages. Find out.

Comment: In any of the interactive web page, you need to do some actions to happen something. So, do something, and then waitFor the hidden properties to appear.

Comment: @Mamun Do you mean to say, I should add some delay in the script.

Comment: @twinj In this solution `$('a[class=CheckRadioFocus]').click()  $('a[id=termLink]').click() ` I am not getting error. But check box doesn't get checked though. BTW how should I do this `I would select the element and test if it contains the class `